# How can I load a .conll file into an Annotation object with Corenlp?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have some files outputted from CoreNLP in `.conll` format, and I want to deserialize them into an `Annotation` object. Does CoreNLP provide a `CONLL-X DocumentReader` method to transform `.conll` file to an `Annotation` object or do I have to create my own DocumentReader?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like [TSVSentenceIterator](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/util/TSVSentenceIterator.java), which reads sentences from a CoNLL-like formatted TSV file.

But, note that the number of Annotations hanging off of an Annotation object is far more than the number of columns in a CoNLL file (e.g., character offsets, etc.), and so this serialization wouldn't be lossless and may have unexpected behavior if you want to keep annotating the object. This is not one of the officially supported lossless serialization strategies.

Comment: I downloaded the project, but i can't find the method that takes the file as input and return the annotation object in TSVSentenceIterator

Comment: You have to read the file yourself, and then pass in the list of lines to the constructor.

Comment: So I have to send my file sentence by sentence into     'public static Sentence toSentence(List<SentenceField> fields, List<String> entries) ' method. Where each string in entries is equivalent to a Token line ?

Comment: I guess yes. You can also use the constructor to queue up a list of sentences. Again, this is not really an officially supported class, so it's a bit rough around the edges.

Comment: What are the equivalent "SentenceField" of a DEPHEAD (Dependency head) and  DEPREL (Dependency relation) ConLL-X format ?